# Login to paypal developer dashboard

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

i'm new to paypal development. My customer want me to integrate paypal in his online shop and i want to use the REST-API and the SDK.

My question: In order to begin i have to login with the paypal account from my customer. Is there another option to create an App with the developer dashboard, without using the credentials from my customer, at least for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create using your own account and make a test. Just signup for the Business Account and automatically you will be getting developer website. From there you can actually do the works, or you can alternatively ask your customer to add you as an alias for doing the testing in developer.